# MVC5 Route not going to Index

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

Here is my action method in TeamController...

```
public class TeamController : BaseController

    {
        // GET: Team
        public ActionResult Index(int id)
        {...}
}
```

Here is the entire route configuration:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

If I use /Team?id=1 it works.  If I use /Team/1 I get a 404.  Using RouteDebugger it shows me that /Team?id=1 is converted to /Team/Index/1 which is correct but shouldn't the index method be invoked by default?

Comment: No, because `/Team/1` means you passing 'Team' as the controller and '1' as the action (and nothing to the optional id parameter)

Comment: You could have use Attribute Routing to overcome this issue  if you are using the latest MVC version. http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/4PK4010514-Understanding-Attribute-Routing-in-ASP.NET-MVC.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments above I fixed it by adding this attribute to the Index method

```
[Route("Team/{id:int:min(1)}")]
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{..}
```